# Using regular expressions in Prometheus relabel_configs source_labels

Tags: regex, amazon-ec2, configuration, prometheus

I'm trying to save the meta labels retrieved from EC2 Service Discovery as target labels. I'm mostly concerned about the tags - every instance contains a lot of them and I would love to gather them all using one simple configuration entry with the usage of regular expression.

The perfect solution seems to be something like this:

```
relabel_configs:
   - source_labels:
      - '__meta_ec2_tag_(.*)'
     target_label: '### use extracted regex group here'
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

> \"__meta_ec2_tag_(.*)\" is not a valid label name"

Does that mean that I can't use regular expressions to describe source labels and that I have to specify each source label separately like in the sample below?

```
- source_labels:
    - '__meta_ec2_tag_Name'
  target_label: 'instance_name'

- source_labels:
    - '__meta_ec2_tag_environment'
  target_label: 'environment'

- source_labels:
    - '__meta_ec2_tag_project'
  target_label: 'project'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
relabel_configs:
   - regex: '__meta_ec2_tag_(.*)'
    replacement: $1
```

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same problem but the previous answer didn't work for me with this error :

> relabel configuration for replace action requires 'target_label' value

I found out that Prometheus now has a `labelmap` option for `relabel_configs` that does this : https://grafana.com/blog/2022/03/21/how-relabeling-in-prometheus-works/#labelmap

TLDR;

```
relabel_configs:
- action: labelmap
  regex: "__meta_ec2_tag_(.*)"
  replacement: "$1"
```